# How to (move) or Add an jpg 'Image' from one div to another div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, image

Hi all i am working on jquery here i have my  html  like this

```
            <div class="grid row-fluid">
          <div>
            <span class="span1">                
            <input type="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox" id="Header" />
            <label for="Header"></label>                
            </span> 
            <span class="span1"> <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://placehold.it/140x140"></span> 
           </div>


             <div>
            <span class="span1">                
            <input type="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox" id="Header" />
            <label for="Header"></label>                
            </span> 
            <span class="span1"> <img class="img-polaroid" src="http://placehold.it/140x140"></span> 
           </div>
           </div>


           <div class="span7" style="border:1px black" id="separate">

                <ul class="thumbnails bootstrap-examples pre-scrollable">
                    <li class="span2">
                      <a href="#">
                        //image shold add here
                      </a>
                      </li>
                     </ul>
         </div>
```

in the above code i have a images and checkbox  ok now i have one empty div  now i want to add those image to the empye div once
i select it the checked images only

```
           $(function () {
          $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
              AddToCart(this);
          });
      });

      function AddToCart(obj) {
          var $this = $(obj).closest('div');
          var img = $this.find('img');
          $('#separate').append(img);
      }
```

how to add image from one div to another div using jquery could u plz help me to do this thanks in advance

Comment: Take image from one div and add it in another div using jQuery append() or appendTo()

Comment: i had tried it says append() or appendTo() not supporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
$(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    AddToCart(this);
  });
});

function AddToCart(obj) {
  var $this = $(obj).closest('div');
  var img = $this.find('img');
  $('#div2').append(img);
}
```

Comment: i had updated my question it says  that AddToCart(obj) is undefined

Comment: first thanks for my reply pulkit it's working but some change insted of check box i need to append by click button could u help me to do this

Comment: replace $('#div2').append(img); with $('#separate').append(img);

Comment: thanks mr.pulkit Mittal thanks very much for ur reply nice coding friend

Comment: You're welcome Shakil. Sorry, I wasn't around my computer, so couldn't reply to your further queries. Pardon me for that.